# Can you launch jQuery from SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I would like to post on

http://anysite.com (any forum/blog/site/...)

a *SVG* IMAGE TAG remotely like this:

< img src="http://myownsite.com/myimage.svg" > (my own site)

in order to launch jQuery/javascript/ajax from it. In detail, I would like the .svg file to open a bigger div including interactive features.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: So, you'd like to be able to post an image on somebody else's site that can take over that site.  I can't think of any _good_ reason why you'd want to do this.

Comment: Are you building some kind of virus? lmao

Answer (score 3):

Browsers don't permit SVG loaded via `<img>` tags to run javascript for security reasons. The security issues they are concerned with are pretty much what you're trying to do, have an image which appears to be one thing but actually isn't.